# How to globally log clicks in a web app via javascript once per dom node?

Tags: javascript, html, events, browser, automated-tests

I have a web application that I'd like to debug during automated tests by registering a global javascript listener that would emit a log event or the like once per click on a given dom node. I don't care whether the solution is pure javascript or uses one of the frameworks. Is their a lightweight way to do this?

Comment: Can you expand on your requirements, possibly with some HTML and any javascript that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you want to log, or where, but perhaps this is what you need:

```
window.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    console.log(e);
    //or
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post', 'url/to/logscript', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode');//or application/json
    var data = {node: (e.target || e.srcElement).tagName,
                other: (e.target || e.srcElement).baseURI};
    xhr.onreadystatechange = callback;//<-- define your own, or leave as is
    xhr.send(data);//serialize or JSON.stringify
},false);
```

In the logscript, you can store the event data you need.
In jQuery, you could do this:

```
$(window).on('click', function(e)
{
    e = e instanceof jQuery ? e[0] : e;//get the real event, I believe jQ wraps the event object...
    $.ajax({method: 'post',
            data: e,
            url: 'path/to/logscript',
            success: function(response)
            {
                //this is the callback function from the vanilla JS snippet
            }
    });
}
```

I wound up using a slightly modified version of the jquery function which JSON-ifies the output and censors it (using code from another example) since it contains circular references (due to the DOM structure).

$(window).on('click', function(e) {
        e = e instanceof jQuery ? e[0] : e;//get the real event, I believe jQ wraps the event object...

```
    $.ajax({method: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(e, censor(e)),
            url: 'debug',
            success: function(response) {
                //this is the callback function from the vanilla JS snippet
            }
    });
});

function censor(censor) {
  return (function() {
    var i = 0;

    return function(key, value) {
      if(i !== 0 && typeof(censor) === 'object' && typeof(value) == 'object' && censor == value)
        return '[Circular]';

      if(i >= 29) 
        return '[Unknown]';

      ++i; 

      return value;
    }
  })(censor);
}
```

The rails controller on the backend looks like this:

```
class DebugController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts params['data']
  end
end
```

Comment: You appear to be missing `, false)` in your javascript example.

Comment: Also, I think `.get(0)` is preferred in jquery over `[0]` and I wonder what happens if `e` contains a circular reference?

Comment: @Xotic750: Why call a function, that just returns the first element of an array anyway? That's just adding overhead...

Comment: True, I just thought that was the jquery preferred way, and as it was a jquery solution ..., I guess that would mean why use jquery at all :)

Comment: @Xotic750: _"Why use jQ at all?"_, [A great question that not enough people are asking themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472714/what-features-does-jquery-provide-that-arent-available-natively-in-the-browsers)... I don't use it, so I tend to _not_ use the jQ preferred ways :)

Answer (score 0):

This will log to the console when a specific node is clicked, uses event delegation (event bubbling), so there is only a single (or global) event listener.

```
var node = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

window.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    if (evt.target === node) {
        console.log("clicked");
    };
}, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/8EWFZ/)

Just click on your question in the jsfiddle and see the console.log

Comment: This works with Chromium v25, Chrome v27 and FireFox v20 that I tested, what browser where you using? And I just tested Opera v12.14 and that is also working.

Comment: Version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 12.04 (25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)

Comment: Then there should be no problem, I thought perhaps you may be using IE8 or earlier, which requires a slightly different syntax. You were clicking on the paragraph <p> that contains "I have a web application that I'd like to debug ...", right?

Comment: @Xotic750: perhaps OP didn't use an `onload` or `readystatechange` handler to assign the DOM reference to `node`? Anyway, your fiddle _is_ working just fine for me, too